# Dataframe in R. output rows

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have the dataframe below

| Año inicio | Año final | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2001 | 4 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2 |

and I would like to transform it into

| Año inicio | Año final | Año | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 2001 | 2000 | 4 |
| 2000 | 2001 | 2001 | 4 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2002 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2003 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2004 | 2 |
| 2002 | 2005 | 2005 | 2 |

using R.

May u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a sequence for each row, stored as a list, and then  unnest it:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tribble(
  ~"Año inicio", ~"Año final",  ~"Resultado",
  2000, 2001,   4,
  2002, 2005,   2,
) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(`Año` = list(seq(`Año inicio`, `Año final`)), .before = "Resultado") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest(`Año`)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   `Año inicio` `Año final`   Año Resultado
#>          <dbl>       <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
#> 1         2000        2001  2000         4
#> 2         2000        2001  2001         4
#> 3         2002        2005  2002         2
#> 4         2002        2005  2003         2
#> 5         2002        2005  2004         2
#> 6         2002        2005  2005         2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with `uncount` and some tweaking:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  uncount(Año_final - Año_inicio + 1) %>%
  mutate(Año = seq(first(Año_inicio), last(Año_final)))

    Año_inicio Año_final Resultado  Año
1       2000      2001         4 2000
2       2000      2001         4 2001
3       2002      2005         2 2002
4       2002      2005         2 2003
5       2002      2005         2 2004
6       2002      2005         2 2005
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Año_inicio = c(2000, 2002), Año_final = c(2001, 
2005), Resultado = c(4, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Hi,Unfortunately row 3 should display 2002, row 4 display 2003 as año

Comment: Thank you. Please see my update. Sorry I did not recognized first. Now it should work.